# Adding event listener in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, events, addeventlistener

I want to reduce my code so here is the question : if i have 10 event listeners and in different situation i have to add or remove them is there a way to put all "addEventListener" in one function and "removeEventListener" in other function and to type "add/removeEventListenerFuction" instead of ten times 10 event listeners.Any answers will help. Thanks for now.

Comment: This question is rather unclear. You will either way have to control all your event listeners, enabling and disabling them in their own life cycle, by hand. If you want a function that would add 10 event listeners, and another that will remove them all at once, yes you can write such a function, but if you want to separately control all 10, I guess you'd better write individual calls to add/removeEventListener.

Comment: What sort of event you are creating and removing often?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to call add/removeEventListener in a loop if you know the event type and store the event handler functions in an array.

```
var events:Array = [{"type":MouseEvent.CLICK,"handler":func1},
    {"type":MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,"handler":func2},
    {"type":MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,"handler":func3},
    {"type":MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,"handler":func4}];

for(var i:int=0; i<events.length; i++) {

    stage.addEventListener(events[i].type,events[i].handler);
    // to remove
    // stage.removeEventListener(events[i].type,events[i].handler);
}
```

I don't see why this would be useful though, maybe if you try to explain what you are trying to do and show some code I can help more.